# how to use already exacted css regular sheet in react app based on css module?

Tags: css, reactjs, module

I'm using the CSS module on my project but I want to use an external library in my project, but the CSS style they provided isn't applied

[image]

Comment: Please include the code in the question instead of posting a screenshot of it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you can do!!!

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../video-js.css">
```

Use the correct path of your CSS file in link tag and Add it in **index.html** of your React App

Note:

Importing CSS files may depend on loaders configured in Webpack of React App.